# component.ts cannot read a class name form service

Tags: angular, angular-services

i have a service by name employee-service.service.ts and it it exports a class with the name 'EmployeeListComponent'

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClientModule } from "@angular/common/http";
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class EmployeeServiceService {

  constructor(private http = HttpClient) { }

  getEmployee(){
    [
      {'id':1,'name':'Gide', 'age':30},
      {'id':2,'name':'Ivan', 'age':34},
      {'id':3,'name':'Maylan', 'age':35},
      {'id':4,'name':'pupa', 'age':36},
    ]
;
};

}
```

and i want to get the array name getEmployee() from my service using the 'component.ts'

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-employee-list',
  templateUrl: './employee-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./employee-list.component.css']
})
export class EmployeeListComponent implements OnInit {

  public employeer = [];
  constructor( private employerservice = EmployeeServiceService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
this.employeer = this.employerservice.getEmployee();
  }


}
```

but i get errors.... in my cli
errorCode:

```
 ERROR in src/app/employee-list/employee-list.component.ts:11:42 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'EmployeeServiceService'.

    11   constructor( private employerservice = EmployeeServiceService) { }
                                                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

**the same problem persists when i try using httpClient with the same procedure
with an error:**

src/app/employee-service.service.ts:8:30 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'HttpClient'.

```
8   constructor(private http = HttpClient) { }
                               ~~~~~~~~~~
```

i sure hope you will understand...please consider im a newbie to anglar

Answer (score 1):

For dependency injection you musts do:

```
constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {}
```

You must use `:` instead of `=`

Reference to angular guide: https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection

Comment: thank you very much @Jorge Mussato but same problem persits

Answer (score 1):

**Service**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class EmployeeServiceService {

  constructor(private http : HttpClient) { }

getEmployee() : void {
let array : Employee[] = [  -- Import Employee.ts accordingly
      {'id':1,'name':'Gide', 'age':30},
      {'id':2,'name':'Ivan', 'age':34},
      {'id':3,'name':'Maylan', 'age':35},
      {'id':4,'name':'pupa', 'age':36},
    ];
};
return array;

}
```

**Component**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-employee-list',
  templateUrl: './employee-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./employee-list.component.css']
})
export class EmployeeListComponent implements OnInit {

  public employeer:Employee[] = []; -- Import Employee.ts accordingly
  constructor( private employerservice : EmployeeServiceService) { } --import accordingly

  ngOnInit(): void {
  this.employeer = this.employerservice.getEmployee();
  }

}
```

**Interface**

```
export interface Employee{
 id : Number;
 name : string;
 age : string;
}
```

Comment: Make a new folder named "Interfaces" in app  folder and then add employee interface file in it

Comment: what will be the file extension please @Wasim

Comment: IEmployee.ts   , I denotes interface

Comment: File extension would be   ".ts"

Comment: CLI ERROR: Cannot find name 'Employee'.34let array : Employee[] = [  -- Import Employee.ts accordingly
    src/app/employee-service.service.ts:32:32 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Import'.32  let array : Employee[] = [  -- Import Employee.ts accordingly32 src/app/employee-service.service.ts:32:39 - error0m TS2304: Cannot find name 'Employee'32  let array : Employee[] = [  -- Import Employee.ts accordingly
    src/app/employee-service.service.ts:32:51 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'accordingly'.32 let array : Employee[] = [  -- Import Employee.ts accordingly @wasim

Comment: Remove lines like this "-- Import Employee.ts " . These were just for justification .

Comment: It looks like you are using these lines in your code  "-- Import Employee.ts accordingly " .Those were just to make sure that you should import it . So remove these lines and just import .

Comment: If you are using Visual Studio Code , Press Ctrl + . [Control plus Dot] . It will automatically highlight import . Then just press enter

Comment: hello wasim thanks a lot for your contribution and Im sorry for the long vac without saying a simple thanks . I actually have held on angular so ill come back for your most honored help at the right time

Answer (score 0):

You have to import the service in your component. Before declaring in constructor.

To do that you must:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { EmployeeServiceService } from '../employeeserviceservice.service'; //add this line, import from correct folder

@Component({
  selector: 'app-employee-list',
  templateUrl: './employee-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./employee-list.component.css']
})
export class EmployeeListComponent implements OnInit {

  public employeer = [];
  constructor( private employerservice = EmployeeServiceService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
this.employeer = this.employerservice.getEmployee();
  }


}
```

Comment: src/app/employee-service.service.ts:44:40 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '../employeeserviceservice.service' or its corresponding type declarations.

    44 import { EmployeeServiceService } from '../employeeserviceservice.service'; //add this line, import from correct folder @Danizavtv

Comment: You have to import from the right location. You do not defined you folder structure. I can't guess.

Comment: hello  Danizavtz thanks a lot for your contribution and Im sorry for the long vac without saying a simple thanks . I actually have held on angular so ill come back for your most honored help at the right time

Comment: Take your time, No worries. I am here to help